# what is the role of "more" here?

Tags: adverbs

1- It `more` than doubles during these day rather one year ago.
2- they have reached 50 or `more` doubles in a season.

Are they adverb?

Comment: In #1 it's an adverb modifying the specific verb ***doubles***. In #2 it's a (pro)noun representing ***a number greater than 50***. You can tell the second usage is a noun, because it can also function as the *subject* of a verb: *I only have 50 today. But **more will arrive** tomorrow*.

Comment: In isolation "more" is a determinative and "than" is a preposition. In the idiom "more than", "more" merges with "than" to form a **modifier** of the item that follows "than"; in this case the verb "doubles". In 2. the determinative "more" functions as **complement** of the prep "or", with the PP "or more" functioning as a dependent of "50", probably a modifier.

Comment: I agree with BillJ except that in 2."or" is a simple conjunction, and "more" is a pronoun = a greater amount.

Comment: @Greybeard  "More" is never a pronoun. It can occur in 'fused' determiner-head constructions such as _I have some money but I always need more_. Here, "more" functions simultaneously as determiner and head ("more money") hence the term 'fused'.

Comment: @BillJ "fused" is a term for two or more words that together produce a particular function, although separately neither word might have that function - we see this in phrasal adjuncts and subjuncts. The question refers to "more" itself - not "more" with a noun assumed as per your example. I had not seen FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica's comment, otherwise I would have simply agreed with it.

Comment: @Greybeard A fused-head construction is one where a single word performs the roles of determiner or modifier and head, e.g. "[**Some** of his remarks] were quite flattering" (fused determiner-head) ~ "Should I wear the red shirt or [the **blue**]?" (fused modifier-head)

Comment: Dear @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, What is your mean about "modifying the **specific verb**"? If the "more", in the former sentence, is an adverb, do you think it is possible to substitute it with "further"?

Comment: @lee: Define "possible". Note that your first example in your question text isn't a "valid" English utterance in the first place, and that can't be fixed by trying to include the word "further". If you're asking whether it's possible to use the sequence ***50 or further*** in a valid utterance, I'd say yes. But probably *only* if that *"**50**"* refers to an actual ***distance***, such as *It's many miles away - probably 50 or further.* But I wouldn't advise it anyway. Stick with ***more***, which also works for other "quantifiable" things besides distance (such as your "doubles").